# How to determine $S_n$ (sum of $n$ terms) formula of given series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$\sum 2^{n-1}   \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} \ \ \ $  // formula for power set elements sum,

sum from $1$ to $10^9$,

I have the series like $1 ,6 ,24 ,80 ,240 \dots$

what would be sum formula for sum of n terms, also explain how to calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find
$$ T_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}2^{n-1}\frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$
it is enough to notice that
$$\begin{eqnarray*} T_N = 2 T_N-T_N &=& \sum_{n=1}^{N}2^n\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}2^{n-1}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\\&=&\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}2^{n-1}\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}2^{n-1}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\\&=&2^{N}\frac{N(N+1)}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}n 2^{n-1}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and by setting $U_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}n 2^{n-1}$, in a similar way, we get $U_N=(N-1)2^N+1$.
In particular:

> $$ T_N = \color{red}{(N^2-N+2)\,2^{N-1}-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\sum_{n=1}^N n(n+1)x^{n-1}=\Bigl(\sum_{n=1}^N x^{n+1}\Bigr)''=\Bigl(\sum_{n=0}^{N+1} x^n\Bigr)''=\cdots$$
Then  use the formula for the partial sum of a geometric series.

Comment: the power outside the braces is n, shouldn't it be N

Comment: Outside the braces? It's a double prime (second derivative).

Comment: But inside the braces a constant value would come for a specific value of n and double derivate of constant is zero

Comment: Please elaborate I have no idea how to solve this correctly

Comment: The derivarive is w.r.t. $x$, not $n$. Do you know the formula for the (partial) sum of a geometric series?